# How to use the result of a linq in a merge method

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net

I got this code

But I got the following errors:

```
Error   1   Instance argument: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<AnonymousType#1>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Data.DataRow>'   

Error   2   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<AnonymousType#1>' does not contain a definition for 'CopyToDataTable' and the best extension method overload 'System.Data.DataTableExtensions.CopyToDataTable<T>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>)' has some invalid arguments 



 var distinctRows = (from DataRow dRow in vwBusPark.toDataTable().Rows
                                    select new { col1 = dRow["BusinessParkID"], col2 = dRow["BusinessParkID"] }).Distinct();

                dataSet.BusinessPark.Merge(distinctRows.CopyToDataTable<DataRow>(), true, System.Data.MissingSchemaAction.Ignore);
```

I tried this:

```
dataSet.BusinessPark.Merge(vwBusPark.toDataTable().Rows.Except(DataRowComparer<UC010_WizardStepBusinessParkDataSet.BusinessParkRow>.Default).CopyToDataTable(), true, System.Data.MissingSchemaAction.Ignore);
```

But I got this 2 errors:

```
Error   2   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<AnonymousType#1>' does not contain a definition for 'CopyToDataTable' and the best extension method overload 'System.Data.DataTableExtensions.CopyToDataTable<T>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>)' has some invalid arguments 

Error   1   Instance argument: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<AnonymousType#1>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Data.DataRow>'
```

Comment: Do you know what `except` means? You may want `Distinct` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those aren't DataRows, so you can't copy them to a DataTable.

Assuming that `BusinessPark` has the same column names as `vwBusPark`, you don't need the LINQ query at all; instead, you can just write

```
vwBusPark.toDataTable().Rows.Except(...).CopyToDataTable()
```

Comment: the vwBusPark is returning me 3 equal rows, I need to use only one copy of the row to be able to use it in the Merge, do you know how? Thank you

Comment: @Luis: Call `Distinct()` or `Except()` with `DataRowComparer<YourType>.Default`

Comment: what should I put inside the Except?    dataSet.BusinessPark.Merge(vwBusPark.toDataTable().Rows.Except().CopyToDataTable(), true, System.Data.MissingSchemaAction.Ignore);
             So far it compiles.

Comment: The collection of rows you want to except (`a except for b`), and `DataRowComparer<YourType>.Default` to tell it to compare by value instead of by reference.  You may want `Distinct()` instead (which still needs the comparer).

Comment: I prefer the linq, this except thing is driving me crazy!!! :)(     dataSet.BusinessPark.Merge(vwBusPark.toDataTable().Rows.Except(vwBusPark.toDataTable().Rows, dataSet.BusinessPark.Rows).CopyToDataTable(), true, System.Data.MissingSchemaAction.Ignore);

Comment: `Except` _is_ LINQ.  It's driving you crazy because you apparently don't know what the word `except` means.  `a except a` will have no results.